# How can I make Firefox annotate links which point to files such as PDFs, which won't be opened in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, pdf, firefox-extensions, links

I want Firefox to scan every page, and for every `<a href="URI">Text</a>` element, I want `Text` to be replaced with `Text [PDF]` if `URI` point to a PDF file (similar to Google Scholar results).

This is because I have Firefox configured to open PDFs externally, and I am annoyed by the extra blank tab from attempting to open them in a new tab, and the popup dialogs are an unwelcome surprise.

If possible, I would like it to automatically do this for every file that is configured to be opened with an external application under Options -> Applications.

I don't need any advanced logic - just a simple regex match for `\.(pdf|PDF)$` would suffice, but a smarter method would of course be even better. It would also be nice if it didn't append the `[PDF]` when it's already appended, such as on the Google Scholar page, to avoid redundancy.

Ideally I'm looking for a Firefox  extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Greasemonkey and a user script. User scripts are scripts that you install in Firefox and that can run on any webpages to do things.

You could install for example: 
http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/8615 - automatically adds icons to non html files (pdf and other):

[image]

You will need to install the Greasemonkey extension **before** installing a user script. (on the userscript site, go to "How do I use this?" under the "Install" link.)

There may be other scripts that only do pdf links.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to edit your user agent style (`.css`), and add a rule that matches `<a href="*.pdf"` elements, and style them with a background of a pdf icon, or highlight them...