# Can I make Firefox display a file of known type (from a Subversion repository) as text?

Tags: windows, firefox, svn

When browsing a Subversion repository using Firefox and the `http`(`s`)`:` URL, I want to take a quick look at text files in the browser itself. However, while Firefox displays unknown file types as text, when I click on a C header it only offers to save it or open it with MSVS (Visual Studio), not to display it.

*Requirements*

- One should be able to open a link as text in the browser in the same or a new tab or window.

  - Preferably also to retain the option to save or open in an application
- One should preferably be able to do so just using mouse clicks.
- While the problem may be related to the Subversion server, a solution for arbitrary sites is clearly preferable.
- A nice extra would be if one could configure the behaviour differently per site or page.

*Constraints*

- It is unlikely that I can get any settings changed in the Subversion server. (I can commit file and attribute modifications normally.)

*Ideas and attempts*

I suspect that the current behaviour is because `.h` is a known file type, but it used to behave differently even though MSVS was installed; the server may however have been older.

I hoped choosing “Open with Notepad” + “Do this automatically” would make it appear in the Options/Applications, letting me change it, but at first that did not work at all, until I thought of refreshing the options page! But even then, I only get the choice of downloading or opening with an application, while I want to open it as text in a Firefox tab.

Manually prefixing `view-source:` to the URL of the repository element works.

It occurs to me that defining an “application” that opens the URL prefixed by `view-source:` in Firefox (in a new tab or the same) might work.

(2017-01-13) Using Firefox Network Monitor I see that the file is served with mime-type `text/x-c`. The related information in `mimeTypes.rdf` is:

```
 <RDF:li RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:text/x-c"/>
 …
 <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:externalApplication:text/x-c"
                  NC:prettyName="notepad.exe"
                  NC:path="C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" />
 …
 <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:handler:text/x-c"
                  NC:alwaysAsk="true">
   <NC:externalApplication RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:externalApplication:text/x-c"/>
   <NC:possibleApplication RDF:resource="urn:handler:local:C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"/>
 </RDF:Description>
 …
 <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:text/x-c"
                  NC:value="text/x-c"
                  NC:editable="true"
                  NC:fileExtensions="h"
                  NC:description="C/C++ Header">
   <NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:handler:text/x-c"/>
 </RDF:Description>
```

Following [Ben’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1087362/571648), setting the Subversion property `svn:mime-type` ↦ `text/plain` solves the problem – it is then served as such, but if that is not wanted, one may want to use the [Mozilla documentation of mimeTypes.rdf](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf) to modify the treatment of `text/x-c` – but it is not clear to me how.

*Related questions*

- [How to have Firefox save txt files automatically instead of opening in browser](https://superuser.com/questions/630109/how-to-have-firefox-save-txt-files-automatically-instead-of-opening-in-browser) — This is the other way round: they want to prevent opening it in the browser; I want to force or offer that.
- [Firefox — How to open a link (to any text-based file) in Vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/830039/firefox-how-to-open-a-link-to-any-text-based-file-in-vim) – This is about getting a desired application into the list. It mentions the interesting extension [Open with](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-with/), but that doesn’t really help.
- [How can I make Google Chrome display a plain text HTTP response, rather than downloading it in a file?](https://superuser.com/questions/126354/how-can-i-make-google-chrome-display-a-plain-text-http-response-rather-than-dow) — This applies to Google Chrome and does not seem to offer a solution. It may however explain the change in behaviour: use of `Content-disposition: attachment` in the header? The trick of prefixing `view-source:` to the URL does work (for `.h`), but requires manual intervention.
- [Make Chrome always open PDFs itself](https://superuser.com/questions/199382/make-chrome-always-open-pdfs-itself) — This applies to Google Chrome but is somewhat similar; it also mentions a Chrome extension [Redirector](https://github.com/chrome-redirector/chrome-redirector) to remove `Content-disposition: attachment`, but I see no documentation there.
- [How can I make Firefox annotate links which point to files such as PDFs, which won't be opened in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/704459/how-can-i-make-firefox-annotate-links-which-point-to-files-such-as-pdfs-which-w) — Sounds powerful enough to do the job, but involves some programming and a learning curve, unless a script is available.

*Notes*

- <sub>Tagged with [svn] as it may depend on how the links are served.</sub>
- <sub>Tagged with [windows] as it may depend on the known file types defined in MS Windows.</sub>
- <sub>The Subversion server is a TeamForge/CollabNet<sup>© 2014</sup> *¿unable to get version by any of the methods in [SO / how-to-find-my-subversion-server-version-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141146/how-to-find-my-subversion-server-version-number)?*.</sub>

Comment: You say, "It is unlikely that I can get anything changed in the Subversion server," does this only mean you can't edit server settings, or does it also mean you cannot commit any changes to files?

Comment: Edited to clarify that I mean the former.

Answer (score 2):

Often SVN servers will automatically use a text context type when serving up .c/.h files, so I'm surprised this isn't already happening for you.

You can try setting the `svn:mime-type` property on these files to "text/plain", or verifying that a different mime type is not already set on those files. SVN servers use this property to determine the http content type in the response to a GET query. Experiment with one or two files before applying it globally, however!

---

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html#svn.advanced.props.special.mime-type

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question to indicate that this works, but that I wonder whether I could instead use `mimeTypes.rdf`.